# Send message to parent VC of modally presented view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to tell my modal views parent view to update its data before the user returns to the screen, but I'm having some difficulties getting the message through.

I've tried all variants of this statement:

```
let parent:Oversikt = self.presentingViewController as Oversikt
    parent.getShifts()
//OR
let parent:Oversikt = self.navigationController.parentViewController as Oversikt
    parent.getShifts()
```

but I keep getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the     `libswiftCore.dylib swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional:`

Can anyone help me? I apologise if this is a stupid question, I'm like most of you very new to swift. Here's an image of my storyboard. The rightmost one wants to communicate with the second leftmost one. 
[image]

Comment: Have you tried presentingViewController?

Comment: @JoshuaSullivan Yep, both with and without including nav controller. Same error as above. Does the navigation controller interfere with modally presenting vcs?

Answer (score 0):

If this was objective-c I would recommend using delegation, but in this case it may be much easier to use NSNotificationCenter. If all you want to do is send a simple message to another view controller, that is one quite simple method.